# Select with pattern from table in SQLite

Tags: sql, sqlite, pattern-matching

I have a table with a column that contains this values

```
patern_number
0936
09154
123456
```

And I have a number which can be anything.
What I want is a select which returns 1 when input number start with one of pattern else return 0
example

```
input number    result    
093628987       1     
0915            0     
0222            0      
091546666       1
```

So can anyone help me?

Comment: select ... where value like '0936%' or value like '09154%' ..... and so on

Comment: hi andre thanks for reply but my pattern numbers is so much and i cannot get like for each one

Comment: it is not a good way i know but you can try like this
(select col2 as 'input_number', '1' as 'result' FROM test.new_table where col2 LIKE '11%') union
 (select col2 as 'input_number', '0' as 'result' FROM test.new_table where col2 not LIKE '11%');

Comment: hi caslaner can you explain more about your query

Comment: About how many patterns do you talk? Sometimes it's technically possible, but won't work performancewise...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN EXISTS(
                        SELECT 1 FROM patern_table
                        WHERE inputNumber Like patern_number || '%') THEN 1
       ELSE 0 END As result
```

<kbd>[`SQL Fiddle Demo`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/b0222/5)</kbd>

Comment: thank you shA.t can you explain more about this || command in your query

Comment: `||` used for concatenating character values ('a' || 'b' = 'ab') ;).